# Why are some jsonl files failing to load in SparklyR

Tags: r, apache-spark, twitter, sparklyr

I am currently trying to read in some jsonl files using SparklyR v 1.3.1 with Spark 2.3.3. While some files read in fine, I am struggling with others, using exactly the same code. Long-ish details below including error messages and packages/code being used.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(sparklyr.nested)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

june1 <- spark_read_json(sc, "june1-aa.jsonl")

june <- spark_read_json(sc, "janetweets_june24.jsonl")
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
and spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the same query.
For example, val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).cache() and then
df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().;
```

The first file appears to read in ok, but any attempt to view the file meets with the following error, and "no tables" is displayed in the connections window, as opposed to the file structure for similar files which can be read in fine.

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Failed to fetch data: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sparklyr.Collectors$.collectLongArr(collectors.scala:87)
    at sparklyr.Collectors$$anonfun$mkColumnCtx$17.apply(collectors.scala:224)
    at sparklyr.Collectors$$anonfun$mkColumnCtx$17.apply(collectors.scala:224)
    at sparklyr.Collectors$ColumnCtx.collect(collectors.scala:183)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.sparklyr$Utils$$collectRows(utils.scala:90)
    at sparklyr.Utils$.collect(utils.scala:114)
    at sparklyr.Utils.collect(utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke.invoke(invoke.scala:147)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:136)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler.read(stream.scala:61)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler$$anonfun$channelRead0$1.apply$mcV$sp(h
```

Owing to the size of these files, these are the first lines on each file, as viewed in terminal.

Sample data in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/y3Zevnpv.

I have tried updating my package to the latest version, deleting and reinstalling, and these files  are definitely in the jsonlines format. This files were pulled from Twitter using the twarc command line tool from a Windows machine. Pls note: I have removed some URLs from above data owing to Stack Overflow guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: What is the leading double question mark `??` in `janetweets_june24.jsonl`? If I remove it, it works. "these files are definitely in the jsonlines format": does not seem to be the case, due to `??`

Comment: @Aurèle I'm not entirely sure why they are there, they starting appearing in the jsonl files created by twarc a llittle while ago. May I ask two more questions? How did you remove the ``??`` and read in those lines? It sounds like something you are doing is solving the issue and would be very grateful to understand what. Thank you!

Comment: I removed them by hand in the sample file. But you might want to do that automatically with a tool like sed